# WSO2ESB: Unable To Start WSO2esb on CentOS

Tags: centos, wso2, wso2-esb

WSO2ESB: Unable To Start WSO2esb on CentOS
Got following Exception while tried to start

```
[root@node2500 bin]# sh wso2server.sh

JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_65

CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to /usr/wso2esb-4.8.1

Exception in thread "Refresh Packages" java.lang.SecurityException: SHA1 digest error for org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/FilteredSourcePackage.class
        at sun.security.util.ManifestEntryVerifier.verify(ManifestEntryVerifier.java:220)
        at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:241)
        at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:228)
        at java.util.jar.JarVerifier$VerifierStream.read(JarVerifier.java:483)
        at sun.misc.Resource.getBytes(Resource.java:124)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:444)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at org.wso2.carbon.server.ChildFirstURLClassLoader.loadClass(ChildFirstURLClassLoader.java:62)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.getLoaderProxy(BundleHost.java:662)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.getBundleLoader(BundleHost.java:652)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl.populateLoaders(PackageAdminImpl.java:281)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl.doResolveBundles(PackageAdminImpl.java:223)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl$1.run(PackageAdminImpl.java:174)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Please help me
Thanks

Comment: WSO2 ESB support Java 1.6. Check with 1.6 and let us know

Comment: installed Oracle JDK 1.7
but faced same problem with open jdk 1.7

Comment: Have you tried with `1.6? We didn't verify WSO2 products with 1.7.

Comment: Tried with 1.7 on my windows machine and working fine.
Also WSO2 - DDS works properly on CentOs
(I have tried without DSS as well)

Answer (score 0):

[JDK-5078608 : Digital signatures are invalid after unpacking](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=5078608)

can it be a JDK bug?

The procedure to pack and signing a jar is broken. Specifically if the jar
is a large one. One will get an error as
jarsigner -verify ./out/foo.jar 
jarsigner: java.lang.SecurityException: SHA1 digest error for original/org/jfree/chart/axis/Axis.class